# librtmp free(): invalid pointer

Tags: c, linux, rtmp

I'm trying to handle packets with librtmp but get a "free(): invalid pointer" error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <librtmp/rtmp.h>
#include <librtmp/log.h>

int main(){
    RTMP *r;
    RTMPPacket packet;

    char uri[] = "rtmp://167.114.171.21:1936/tinyconf app=tinyconf timeout=180000 live=1 conn=S:ROOMNAME swfurl=http://tinychat.com/embed/Tinychat-11.1-1.0.0.0602.swf";

    RTMP_LogLevel loglvl=RTMP_LOGDEBUG2;
    RTMP_LogSetLevel(loglvl);

    r = RTMP_Alloc();
    RTMP_Init(r);
    RTMP_SetupURL(r, (char*)uri);
    RTMP_Connect(r, NULL);

    while (RTMP_IsConnected(r)) {
        RTMP_ReadPacket(r, &packet);
        if (!RTMPPacket_IsReady(&packet))
            continue;
        RTMP_ClientPacket(r, &packet);
        RTMPPacket_Free(&packet);
    }

    RTMP_Close(r);
    RTMP_Free(r);

    return 1;
}
```

[Here's a link to the log/backtrace](http://pastebin.com/srT4GPNM). (As it's pretty long)

I'm unsure to why this is happening, is this a problem with my code or librtmp itself?

Comment: `packet` is uninitialized.  And per the logs you posted, your process crashes in what's likely your first call to `RTMP_ReadPacket()`, which is the first time you use `packet`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't think that's the problem here as I've seen other code (for example the python-librtmp bindings) and there the packet is created with `RTMPPacket packet;`. But I'll play around with it a little bit more later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `RTMPPacket_Alloc(packet, size);` worked, although I've seen other code not using it (I think). Anyway here is a working example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <librtmp/rtmp.h>
#include <librtmp/log.h>

int main(){
    RTMP *r;
    RTMPPacket packet;
    RTMPPacket_Alloc(&packet, 4096);

    char uri[] = "rtmp://167.114.171.21:1936/tinyconf app=tinyconf timeout=180000 live=1 conn=S:ROOMNAME swfurl=http://tinychat.com/embed/Tinychat-11.1-1.0.0.0602.swf";

    RTMP_LogLevel loglvl=RTMP_LOGDEBUG2;
    RTMP_LogSetLevel(loglvl);

    r = RTMP_Alloc();
    RTMP_Init(r);
    RTMP_SetupURL(r, (char*)uri);
    RTMP_Connect(r, NULL);

    while (RTMP_IsConnected(r)) {
        RTMP_ReadPacket(r, &packet);
        if (!RTMPPacket_IsReady(&packet))
            continue;
        RTMP_ClientPacket(r, &packet);
        RTMPPacket_Free(&packet);
    }

    RTMP_Close(r);
    RTMP_Free(r);

    return 1;
}
```